# Android device as touch input for Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-8-preview, android, input-device

I am looking to do some Windows 8 development, as you may know they ethos is "touch first".

There is a built-in simulator that I can use in Visual Studio but I would prefer to use some real hardware. I currently own a Galaxy note (Android phone / tablet), and was wondering if could use that as an input device.

Preferably I would like to be able to clone my desktop to my note and be able to control it there via multitouch.

If this is not possible, I would settle for the ability to simply use it as a multitouch touchpad.

Anyone know how I could go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any android device to emulate multi-touch on windows 8 , here is how you will do it :

1. Install this on your android device : 
   http://code.google.com/p/tuiodroid/
2. Install EcoTUIODriver by Interface Ecology Lab on your windows 8 machine : 
   https://github.com/ecologylab/EcoTUIODriver

Answer (score 3):

There's : Win8 Metro TestBed from Splashtop

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.splashtop.remote.pad.win8&hl=en

But my device is not supported and it runs slow apparently.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the free DroidMote Client on your android device:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.videomap.droidmoteclient

And install the free DroidMote Server on your Windows 8 pc:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fitAvuHFAGQ